# Two microcontrollers outputs signal into single input pin (of a motor controller)

Tags: arduino, circuit-design

I built a system where a motor controller takes input from seeduino Xiao. It opens/close gate. I want to upgrade the system and preserve what is already working.

I have second microcontroller with different functionalities programmed in. I want to connect it's output of the second MCU to the same motor input that the first MCU is connected.
It will look like this:

```
MCU_1_out_pin ---
                 +---- in_pin_MC
MCU_2_out_pin ---
```

MC is a motor controller
MCU is seeduino Xiao

I am afraid of what will happen if I put high state on 1st, but not 2nd MCU. Will the current flow into the output pin? (I think there is some resistor in there to protect against it). Just to be safe I was thinking to put there some "OR gate" or diodes (diodes will have probably to big of a voltage drop). What other solutions exists (maintaining the architecture of two MCU) ?

Comment: Do you write the code for both microcontrollers? It is not safe to parallel outputs when one is high and one is low. But it's possible to use only high/input or low/input, then when both are input, you use a so-called "pull-[up/down] resistor" to make it the other way. E.g. a resistor between in_pin_MC and ground, then when both MCUs are set to input, it's low, but either one can set to high and override the resistor.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the 2nd input?

Comment: It’s usually bad juju to connect two totem pole outputs together. Usual trick would be to use diodes. Use Schottky diodes if voltage drop is an issue or a or logic gate. Yes you can change your code to achieve a similar result as explained above.

Comment: What you might want to do depends if the input is active high or active low, and how each MCU needs to drive the input, is there a pull resistor, and if the logic levels come from same supply.

Comment: If he just uses "npn" output (pulldown only, resistor for pullup) there won't be any issues.

Comment: @Kartman your comment is the answer. I'm gonna use an **OR gate**
I do write code for both MCUs. They differ in a way they take input from the user. I just plan to migrate to the second one, but my time is limited, so for now I want this fast trick as a temporary solution to keep both inputs operational.